# I'm reinstalling my Linux desktop, how do I keep SSH logins working?

Tags: ssh

Long ago I generated a key pair using `ssh-keygen` and I used `ssh-copy-id` to enable login onto many development VMs without manually having to enter a password. I've also uploaded my public key on GitHub, GitLab and similar to authenticate to git repositories using `git@` instead of `https://`.

How can I reinstall my Linux desktop and keep all these logins working? Is backing up and restoring `~/.ssh/` enough?

Comment: That is one of many reasons why when you install a new Linux environment you should have a partition for `/` and another one for `/home`

Comment: @olegario I disagree. I've used Linux for the better part of my life, and currently administrate >100 machines, but I've always found a separate `/home` partition both a hassle and of limited use. I understand some people find it useful, and that's fine, but I don't think it's adequate help for the OPs situation anyway.

Comment: There's really no advantage to a partition over just backing up and restoring `/home` via `tar` or any other means, unless you plan to reuse the existing partitions, which is risky anyway with most OS installers that will happily wipe them, unless it's on a separate physical disk you remove during install.

Comment: Once you're done with the reinstall, no matter how exactly you do it, you might want to reconsider having just one key pair for everything.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to back up your private keys, at the very least. They cannot be regenerated without having to replace your public key everywhere. These would normally have a name starting with `id_` and no extension.

The public keys can be regenerated with this command: `ssh-keygen -y -f path/to/private/key`. Your user configuration (a file called "config") could also be useful if you have set any non-defaults.

All of these files would *normally* be in ~/.ssh, but check first!

Answer (score 30):

For *outgoing* SSH connections, backing up your key pair is enough. For convenience, you might just backup your `~/.ssh` directory and restore it onto the new installation.

Normally backing up and restoring that directory is enough, but it is possible to store the keys elsewhere by either using custom settings in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, or by using a SSH-agent and `ssh-add` to pick up the keys to be used on outgoing connections from an arbitrary location.

If you have *incoming* SSH connections, you might also consider backing up the SSH host keys at `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*`. If you don't backup these, new host keys will be automatically generated by `sshd` as it starts for the first time on the new installation, and any incoming SSH connections will show the "SSH host key mismatch, someone may be doing something bad!" error message and usually reject the connection unless someone deletes the old host key on the SSH client and explicitly accepts the new one.

It sounds like you might not have incoming SSH connections on your Linux desktop system, so I'm mentioning this only for the sake of completeness. But on server systems, or if you have significant SSH-based automation set up, acknowledging a changed host key might be a major hassle.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. To login **from** other machines, you have to keep the host key, usually stored in `/etc/ssh`, file names are `ssh_host_*` (several files for different algorithms).

Comment: Note that if you're SSHing *in*, you might want to rotate the *host* keys anyway; but this depends on your key management situation (e.g. the keys were last generated years ago, and you don't have `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key` yet, or you have a RSA 1024 key, or even a DSS key).